# Can't clear bitmap render target with ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget::Clear() (Direct2D)

Tags: bitmap, directx, textures, direct2d

I want to obtain a fully clear and transparent bitmap in `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget`, but instead of clearing, the `Clear()` method alpha-blends the clearing color with the existing bitmap content. I.e. if the clearing color is (0,0,0,0) then nothing changes, if the color is partially opaque then the existing content is partially dimmed, but never gets erased completely.

I create the `ID2D1BitmapRenderTarget` using `ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateCompatibleRenderTarget()` from a Direct3D texture, and I have verified that the pixel format of the bitmap is `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` and alpha mode is `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED`, so clearing with transparent color should really work but it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
D2D1_SIZE_U bitmapPixSize = {...};
D2D1_PIXEL_FORMAT bitmapPixFormat = {};
// Use the same pixel format and alpha mode as the source texture render target
bitmapPixFormat.alphaMode = D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_UNKNOWN;
bitmapPixFormat.format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
textureRenderTarget->CreateCompatibleRenderTarget(
    nullptr, 
    &bitmapPixSize, 
    &bitmapPixFormat, 
    D2D1_COMPATIBLE_RENDER_TARGET_OPTIONS_NONE, 
    &bitmapRenderTarget);

// Doesn't work
bitmapRenderTarget->Clear(nullptr);
D2D1_COLOR_F color = { .r = 0, .g = 0, .b = 0, .a = 0 };
// Doesn't work either
bitmapRenderTarget->Clear(&color);`
```

Please help!!!

Comment: have you tried other alphaMode values for bitmapPixFormat?

Comment: Yes, I tried the `D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_STRAIGHT` but then I get the error "D2D DEBUG ERROR - The combination of alpha mode and DXGI format supplied are not compatible with one another.", because my DXGI swap chain is also created with premultiplied alpha. I tried to change DXGI to straight alpha but then I get "DXGI ERROR: IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain: Alpha blended swapchains must be created with CreateSwapChainForComposition, or CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow with the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_FOREGROUND_LAYER flag. But I need it for HWND, not for composition. So I turned back to premultiplied.